# Display simple JSP with Spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to display a simple JSP file with Spring but can't get it to work.
Here is my `HelloController.java`:

```
package com.javatpoint;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView mymethod(){
        return new ModelAndView("hellopage","msg","Hello First Spring");
    }
}
```

I got an `index.jsp` file:

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>

<%= java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime() %>

<a href="hello">click here</a>

</body>
</html>
```

A web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

A spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"> 

<context:component-scan base-package="com.javatpoint"></context:component-scan>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

And my simple hellopage.jsp

```
Message is: ${msg}
```

But when I run the spring application and go to `localhost:8080/hello` I just get this error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sat Dec 03 12:52:32 CET 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Thats the folder structure of my files:

[image: directory structure]

You can download my code [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108388353/SpringMVC.zip) to run it by yourself.

By the way, I got this code from [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/spring-3-mvc-tutorial).

Can someone help me to find out what I'm doing wrong?
I'm not very familiar with spring and those web.xml and spring-servlet.xml so I guess there is something wrong there.

Comment: What is application root ? or if you deployed into Tomcat what is your projectname in webapps folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Thymeleaf` dependency as below:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency
```

Try with this for another error in your comments:

```
<bean id="templateResolver"
  class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
   <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
   <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
 </bean>
```

Also, with this in index.jsp & hellopage.jsp file:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" 
xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3"
xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<title>k</title> 
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast replay. I added the dependency and get this error now: `Error resolving template "hellopage", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers` Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: I added the bean to my `spring-servlet.xml` and `index.jsp` but I still get the same error.. Am I missing something? Were you able to run the application with these changes in my source files?

Comment: @Peter, also add the html code in hellopage.jsp file.